# When is disjunctive-が appropriate in connecting sentences?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, particle-が

Consider the following:

> [1] 僕は日本人ではなく,　シンガポール人です。　(I'm not Japanese, I'm Singaporean)
>
> [2] 僕は日本人ではないが, シンガポール人です。 (I'm not Japanese but Singaporean)

Comparing my sentences to the worked examples in my grammar practice workbook, [1] would be correct while [2] would be wrong.

**(Question)** Is [2] a valid sentence?

**(Side Question)** Can I read `ではなく` as `じゃなく`?

Comment: 僕は日本人ではないが, シンガポール人です and “I'm not Japanese but Singaporean” mean different things.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto How different are they? Are you mentioning the scope of negation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your textbook is wrong in saying that [2] is wrong. Whenever `P` and `Q` work in the opposite direction towards expectation of `R`, `P ではないが Q` is okay. For example, it is fine in the following context:

> A: だれか、アジア人はいませんか。
>   　'Is there any Asian?'
>   B: 僕は日本人です。
>   　'I am a Japanese.'
>   C: 僕は日本人ではないが, シンガポール人です。
>   　'I am not a Japanese, but am a Singaporean.'

In this context, `僕は日本人ではない` closes up one possibility of C being an Asian, but then, `シンガポール人です` opens up another possibility, working towards the expectation of, and in fact affirming, C being an Asian.

Usually, you read as it is written. If you want `じゃなく`, you will usually write so. But it is not that wrong to read `ではなく` as `じゃなく`. It is wrong/correct to the extent that reading English `cannot` as `can't` is.

Actually, even when `P` and `Q` do not work in the opposite direction, you can use `PがQ` as long as `P` is providing a new topic into the discourse.

> 彼は試験に受かったが、これは普段からの努力の賜物だ。
>   'He passed the examination, and that is due to his consistent effort.'

Comment: ~ないで、~ではなく、~ないですから、~ないので are the same meaning.
what are most of priority?

Comment: @ZarNge perhaps a new question? I think the comments section is not big enough to explain the differences in the above 4 you mentioned.